# Encrypt QRCode payload with input length the same as the output length

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, qr-code, cryptojs

Im trying to encrypt the data payload of a dynamic QRCode.

We have an app that generates a QRCode from dynamic data and we would like to have an option to encrypt the payload if so desired.

Because the size limitations inherent in QRCodes, one of the requirements is that the **payload data** must be the same size as the **encrypted data**. If the encrypted data is different/too large, the QRCode may fail to scan/decode correctly.

I have tried to use AES encryption in CTR mode (stream as opposed to block) as suggested elsewhere. The result is that the output cipher bytes are same size as the input bytes, however converting the bytes to a char friendly format (eg base64) produces a string length much longer than that of the original payload.

Is there way to encrypt a string so that the plain text and encrypted string length are the same?

According to this MIT pdf located here, https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.857/2014/files/12-peng-sanabria-wu-zhu-qr-codes.pdf, they mention already existing solutions which they call SEQR (Symmetric Encrypted QR) codes. However I am yet to find a solution which, as mentioned in the article, produces an encrypted output that is the same length is the plain text input.

We are using C# .NET in our backend, the ZXing QRCode library and Javascript on our front end, with CryptoJS.

I have also created a JSFiddle demostrating AES in CTR mode.

http://jsfiddle.net/s1jeweja/5/

```
var options = { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding };  

/*** encrypt */  
var json = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("some plain text", "secret", options);  
var ciphertext = json.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.UTF8);  
document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = ciphertext;
//debugger;
/*** decrypt */  
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(json, "secret", options);  
var plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);  



document.getElementById("decrypt").innerHTML = plaintext; // text can be a random lenght
```

Comment: QR codes have no difficulty carrying raw binary data, so the requirement for a "char friendly" payload seems arbitrary and counterproductive. I also think you should consider if it's really safe to have encrypted payloads of the exact same size as the plaintexts. For example, does it matter that your system is vulnerable to [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack)?

Comment: I was under the impression that storing the payload as binary was not an option, I will revisit that. 

You are right about the vulnerability risk. Context: We are storing personal information in the QRCode and printing them for an event. Its more a matter of preventing other attendees from collecting attendee information without their permission. If someone were to somehow collect all the attendees physical QRCodes and then take advantage of a vulnerability, I would think there would be easier ways to harvest this kind of information? I would think it would be an acceptable risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) which converts plaintext text characters to cyphertext text characters.  One way to do that is an adaptation of the classic [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).  Generate a keystream of pseudo-random numbers in the range 0..25 and use them to do a cyclic shift of the plaintext characters round the alphabet.

You are already using AES-CTR, so use that to generate your keystream.  Mask off five bits of the keystream.  If those five bits are in 0..25 then use them to do a cyclic shift of the next plaintext character to the corresponding cyphertext character.  If the five bits are in the range 26..31 then discard them and get another five bits.

In pseudocode, this looks something like:

```
textToTextEncode(plaintext)
  for each character p in plaintext
    c <- p + getNextShift()
    if c > 'z'
      c <- c - 26
    end if
    write(c, cyphertextFile)
  end for
end textToTextEncode()

getNextShift()
  repeat
    b <- getNextByte(AES-CTR)
    b <- b & 0b00011111  // Binary mask.
  until b < 26
  return b
end getNextShift()
```

For decryption you will need to subtract the shift value and add 26 if the result falls below 'a'.

ETA: As you can see from the comments below, you will need a nonce (AKA IV) that is unique for each QRCode.  Set aside a fixed number of bytes at the start or end of each QRCode for the nonce.  Do not encrypt those bytes, you have to leave them in the clear.  Extract them from the full QRCode and use them to initialise your AES-CTR method.  Then use that AES-CTR to decrypt the rest of that QRCode.  The more bytes, up to 16, the more security you will have.

Comment: This isn't secure at all. Suppose Donald Trump attends the event and receives a QR code where his name is encrypted as `TKRREB NZIBP`. He can then extract the keystream directly from this information, and can use it to decrypt any other name, e.g., `RWVRVI IJOBA` = Barack Obama.

Comment: AES-CTR requires a nonce for security.  Part of the `options` parameter of the code the questioner supplied.  There is always additional information for secure encryption: key, IV/nonce etc.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is requesting that the ciphertext is the same size as the plaintext, so there isn't any IV or nonce.

Comment: Or key?  You cannot use AES-CTR correctly without extra information.

Comment: So don't. (And yes *of course* you need a key, but you're not going to add that to the ciphertext now, are you?)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the restriction of the input type which has to be a string is more or less historical and was never changed in the past. Regardless of the possibility of different barcode formats to encode byte data.

Here is a small code snippet which works for me:

```
  [Test]
  public void Test_Binary_Data_Encoding_As_Char()
  {
     var writer = new BarcodeWriter
     {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
        {
           ErrorCorrection = ErrorCorrectionLevel.L,
           CharacterSet = "ISO-8859-1"
        }
     };

     // Generate dummy binary data
     var binaryData = new byte[256];
     for (var i = 0; i < binaryData.Length; i++)
        binaryData[i] = (byte)i;

     // Convert the dummy binary data to a string
     var binaryDataAsChar = new char[binaryData.Length];
     for (var i = 0; i < binaryDataAsChar.Length; i++)
        binaryDataAsChar[i] = (char)binaryData[i];
     var binaryDataAsString = new String(binaryDataAsChar);

     // encode the string as QR code
     var qrcode = writer.Write(binaryDataAsString);

     // decode the QR code (full roundtrip test)
     var reader = new BarcodeReader();
     var binaryDataAsStringFromQrCode = reader.Decode(qrcode);
     var binaryDataAsStringFromQrCodeText = binaryDataAsStringFromQrCode.Text;

     // a little hack, because the barcode reader converts the \n to \r\n
     binaryDataAsStringFromQrCodeText = binaryDataAsStringFromQrCodeText.Remove(10, 1);

     // convert the result string to the byte array
     var binaryDataFromQrCode = new byte[256];
     for (var i = 0; i < binaryDataFromQrCode.Length; i++)
        binaryDataFromQrCode[i] = (byte)binaryDataAsStringFromQrCodeText[i];

     // Assert, that the representation of the result string and the byte array is equal to the source
     Assert.That(binaryDataAsString, Is.EqualTo(binaryDataAsStringFromQrCodeText));
     for (var i = 0; i < binaryData.Length; i++)
        Assert.That(binaryDataFromQrCode[i], Is.EqualTo(binaryData[i]), "position " + i + " is wrong");
  }
```